# PHP, Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php

I am receiving the following error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

I understand what this means, just confused as to why I am getting this.  Essentially I am doing

```
$allFlights = $em->getRepository("NickAlertBundle:Alert")->getSpecificAlert($id);
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($allFlights);

$wCommand = $allFlights[0]['searchCommand'];
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($wCommand);
```

If I output $allFlights, I see

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(5) { 
        ["id"]=> int(11) 
        ["searchCommand"]=> string(20) "@BA@A20APRLONNYC0100" 
        ["classes"]=> string(1) "G" 
        ["pseudos"]=> string(7) "124,P76" 
        ["flight_number"]=> string(5) "BA175" 
    } 
}
array(0) { }
```

The second output $wCommand shows

```
string(20) "@BA@A20APRLONNYC0100"
```

So it is getting the correct data, so not to sure why I am seeing this error.  Does the above look correct?

Thanks

Comment: you'll also get that error if you're trying to output a key that doesn't exist in the array. are you outputting $allFlights in a print_r or just echoing the array?

Comment: Just using the Symfony2 version of var_dump.  But I get the error even without this, I just put it there to show the data I am receiving